# Clipboard.js Copy multiple elements with One Button Click

Tags: jquery, html, clipboard.js

This is a new question but relates [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48131501/add-a-column-to-a-table-generated-by-jquery-function-from-csv/48131930?noredirect=1#comment83254494_48131930). In short I am now able to copy a cell in a generated table to the clipboard. What I would like to do now is add more text to the clipboard using the same button. I have tried using the imperative API as the [docs](https://clipboardjs.com/) suggest but I can still only copy the original target. How do I copy multiple elements using clipboard.js with one button click?

My Code So Far:

```
<script>
var place_id = ''; //addme
var startDate = '{{request.GET.start_date}}';//addmee
var endDate = '{{request.GET.end_date}}';//addmee

var clipboard = new Clipboard('.cp_btn',{
    text: function(trigger) {
        var toCopy = document.querySelector('#toCopy').value;
        var dateCopy = document.querySelector('#dateCopy').value;
        var errorCopy = document.querySelector('#errorCopy').value;
        return toCopy + dateCopy + errorCopy;
    }
});

clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
    console.info('Action:', e.action);
    console.info('Text:', e.text);
    console.info('Trigger:', e.trigger);

    e.clearSelection();
});

clipboard.on('error', function(e) {
    console.error('Action:', e.action);
    console.error('Trigger:', e.trigger);
});

$(function() {

    var start = moment(startDate);
    var end = moment(endDate);

    function cb(start, end) {
        $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
        init();
    }

    $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
        startDate: start,
        endDate: end,
        ranges: {
           'Today': [moment(), moment()],
           'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
           'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
           'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
           'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
           'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
        }
    }, cb);

    cb(start, end);

});

function clearString(str){
   var str = str.replace(/\"/g, "");
   return str;
  }
  function csvToTable(myReturn){
    var cellToCopyIndex = 0;
    var allRows = myReturn.split(/\r?\n|\r/);
    var table = '<table class="tablesorter">';
    for (var singleRow = 0; singleRow < allRows.length; singleRow++) {
      if (singleRow === 0) {
        table += '<thead>';
        table += '<tr>';
      } else {
        table += '<tr>';
      }
      var rowCells = allRows[singleRow].split(',');
      for (var rowCell = 0; rowCell < rowCells.length; rowCell++) {
        if (singleRow === 0) {
          table += '<th style="padding: 15px;">';
          table += clearString(rowCells[rowCell]);
          table += '</th>';
        } else {
          table += '<td>';
          if(rowCell==cellToCopyIndex){
            table += '<input type="text" id="toCopy_'+singleRow+'" value="'+clearString(rowCells[rowCell])+'" readonly>';
          }else {
              table += clearString(rowCells[rowCell]);
          }
          table += '</td>';
        }
      }
      if (singleRow === 0) {
        table += '</tr>';
        table += '</thead>';
        table += '<tbody>';
      } else {
        table += '<td>' +
            '<button class="cb_btn" data-clipboard-target="#toCopy_'+singleRow+'"' +
            'style="color:#60B7BA;\n' +
            '    font-size: 20px;\n' +
            '    margin-top: 0;\n' +
            '    padding-top: 11px;">View Logs';
        table += '</button></td>';
        table += '</tr>';
      }
    }
    table += '</tbody>';
    table += '</table>';
    return table;
  }
  function showLogData(name, domElement, csv){
    csv = csv || false;

    var selStatus = jQuery('#txtselstatus').val();
    jQuery('#returndatalog').css('display', 'none');
    if (selStatus == "")
    {
      alert("Please enter status")
      jQuery('#txtselstatus').focus();
    }else
    {
      jQuery(domElement).html("<img src='/static/img/loader.gif'/>");
      jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/ajax/generatelogdata',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            "chkstatus":"",
            'place_id': place_id,
            'queryname': name,
            'startDate': $("#reportrange").data('daterangepicker').startDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
            'endDate': $("#reportrange").data('daterangepicker').endDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD")
        },
        success: function(response){
          ///console.log(response)
           jQuery('#returndatalog').css('display', 'block');

          if(typeof response =='object')
          {
            var myReturn = response.response;
            if (csv) {
                jQuery(domElement).html(csvToTable(myReturn));
                jQuery(domElement + " table").tablesorter();
                new Clipboard('.cb_btn');
            }
            else {
                jQuery(domElement).html(response.response.replace(/\"/g,""));
            }
          }
          if(response.error){

          }
          else{

          }
        },
        error:function(response){

        }
      });
    }
  }

function init() {
    showLogData('globallogs_places', '#returngloballogsplaces', true);
}
</script>
```

html:

```
{% block css_includes %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/tablesorter/style.css?rand=1" type="text/css" /> <!--addme -->
{% endblock %}
{% block js_includes %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/admin_stats.js?v={{version}}"></script>
<script src="/static/js/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript"  src="/static/js/admin.js?v={{version}}"></script>
<script src="/static/js/handlebars.min-v1.1.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript"  src="/static/js/clipboard.min.js"></script><!--addme-->
<!-- datepicker add -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript"  src="/static/js/jq.tablesorter.js"></script><!--addme -->
<!--<script  type="text/javascript"  src="/static/js/logs.js?rand=9"></script><!--addme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3/css/bootstrap.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />
{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
<br>
<h3>Select a Date</h3>
<br>
<div id="reportrange" class="pull-left" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 23%">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
    <span></span> <b class="caret"></b>
</div>
<br>
<h3>Errors:</h3>
<br>
<br>
<div id="returngloballogsplaces" align="left"></div>
<div>
<input type="hidden" id="dateCopy" data-clipboard-target="{{request.GET.end_date}}" value="{{request.GET.end_date}}" >
</div>
<div>
<input type="hidden" id="errorCopy" data-clipboard-target="httpRequest.status>=300 httpRequest.status<=499" value="httpRequest.status>=300 httpRequest.status<=499" >
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
{% endblock %}
```